# Как правильно согласовать слова?

Tags: грамотная-речь

1. Настроить домов или настроить дома?
2. "Пренебречь совет друга" - здесь нарушены ли нормы?

Answer (score 1):

1. Глагол **настроить** в значении '*построить в каком-л. количестве*' может управлять и родительным, и винительным падежом: настроить чего-что. Например: *Настроить кварталы 
   жилых домов. Настроить железных дорог. Он настроит дымных келий по уступам гор...* 
   (Лермонтов). Примеры взяты из словаря-справочника Розенталя "Управление в русском языке".
2. Глагол **пренебречь** управляет только творительным падежом: пренебречь кем-чем. Писать нужно: *пренебречь советом друга*.